# Вывод Date формата в виду "yyyy" из собственного класса

Tags: c#, классы, дата, datetime, методы

Для работы с проектом я сделал свой класс `Date` для того, чтобы было удобнее работать с датами.
Я использую метод:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{year}-{(int)month:d2}-{day:d2}";
}
```

Который всегда для меня выводит строку: `yyyy-mm-dd` но мне нужно также, чтобы я мог получать на вывод `yyyy-mm` и `yyyy`, если конечно же это соответствует введенным данным.
Сам класс умеет принимать данные такого формата, прикрепляю три метода, подтверждающие это, если нужна будет доп. информация отредактирую вопрос.

```
public Date(int year, int month, int day)
{
    this.year = year;
    this.month = (Month)month;
    this.day = day;
}

public Date(int year, int month)
{
    this.year = year;
    this.month = (Month)month;
}

public Date(int year)
{
    this.year = year;
}
```

В них еще были Exception, убрал чтобы не загромождать вопрос.

Подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: Структура DateTime достаточна удобна для работы с датой, чтобы выводить её в нужном вам формате необходимо вызвать метод ```ToString()```, а параметром передать например ```"yyyy-mm-dd"``` или ```"yy-m-d"```.

Comment: @AlAvenger но это не решает моей проблемы, поэтому было принято решение создать новый класс и работать с ним

Comment: Проблема, которая возникла в ходе создания программы

Comment: В чем проблема непосредственно?

Comment: @AlAvenger Я в программе создаю файлы, которые потом применяются для работы с программой и при создании DateTime ... = new DateTime(2020,01,01) в файле генерируется  корректно, но создать DateTime ... = new DateTime(2020) я не могу, так как сгенерируется  0001-01-01

Comment: Вы можете сделать так: ```new DateTime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)```. Сделайте конструкторы вашего класса похожие на DateTime, но с дефолтным значением 0 у часов, минут, секунд. В итоге DateTime.ToString() вам будет возвращать ```01.01.2021 0:00:00```, а если необходимо отформатировать вывод - используйте перегрузки ```ToString``` у дефолтного ```DateTime```.

Comment: Но мне не нужно `01.01.2021 0:00:00` и перегрузки с помощью `.ToString`, мне конкретно поставлена задача, и я хочу добиться универсального метода, при котором смогу просто через `new` создавать дату любого формата. Если вы желаете помочь, то мы можем перейти в чат, где я смогу объяснить подробнее и если нужно дать ссылку на gitlab

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130854/discussion-between-alavenger-and-ilya-kvashnin).

Comment: Не лепите костыли. Читайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) по `DateTime`. Суждение о том, что `DateTime` не может решить задачу, неверно. Вы просто поленились его изучить.

Comment: @aepot Но вы ведь не знаете всей ситуации, я советовался с преподавателем, либо он считает, что это будет полезная практика для меня, либо просто того мнения, что новый класс будет удобнее

Comment: `Но вы ведь не знаете всей ситуации` так я исхожу из того что показано в вопросе. Как объяснили, такие и выводы. Но я уверен, что какая бы там ситуация не была, все упирается в ввод и вывод дат, а `DateTime` с этим прекрасно обучен справляться. Окей, вы можете показать весь класс целиком, чтобы я не придумывал недостающие фрагменты для написания ответа? И опишите как то что вы написали, будет применяться. Попробуем и ваше решение разобрать и пример с `DateTime` показать.

Comment: Да не, спорю, что в вопросе указано не все, но и в вопросе я спрашивал о работе с новым классом, а не `DateTime`, даже если это будет изобретение велосипеда, просто такова задача.
И с пользователем выше мы её решили, и все же пришлось прибегнуть к созданию нового класса. Я думаю нам не стоит искать второе решение этой проблемы, чтобы не тратить ваше время?

Comment: На заметку: в .NET 6 появился тип [DateOnly Struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Решение моей проблемы, приведенное пользователем "AlAvenger".
Остается добавить операторы и класс может работать с любым форматом даты ("yyyy-MM-dd" либо "yyyy-MM" или "yyyy").

```
class Date
{
    private int _year;
    private int? _month;
    private int? _day;
    public int Year { get { return _year; } }
    public int Month
    {
        get
        {
            if (_month.HasValue == false)
                return 1;

            return _month.Value;
        }
    }
    public int Day
    {
        get
        {
            if (_day.HasValue == false)
                return 1;

            return _day.Value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime DateTime { get { return _date; } }
    public Date(int year, int? month = null, int? day = null)
    {
        _year = year;
        _month = month;
        _day = day;

        _date = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day);

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _date.ToString();
    }
    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return _date.ToString(format);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это вышло случайно, просто написал "```class Date", поправил

Comment: `int?` нет необходимости использовать nullable, так как `0` в качестве значения по умолчанию вполне подходит, у вас же в практическом смысле не может быть нулевого дня или месяца. То есть, если 0, то не задано.

Comment: Ну код, я написал, что не мой, я пока не могу его применить к своему проекту, так как нужно дописать операторы, но если что буду знать об этом, спасибо.
Вы хотите чтобы я изменил это и тут?

Comment: о каких операторах речь? `int?` везде замените на `int`, а `null` на `1`. И не нужно будет извращаться со свойствами.

Comment: операторы + - и т.д, чтобы производить операции, но это не важно

Comment: Я вас понял и иногда мне нужны значения null, но если кому то нет, думаю ваш комментарий будет полезен

Comment: + и - с днями? Это большая сложная задача, так как нужно помимо дней в месяце еще учитывать [високосный год или нет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61527145/12888024). Конечно, это решается математически, но не просто. По поводу null я не согласен, это кроме усложения логики ничего не дает. Тот же DateTime не поддерживает nullable.

Comment: Кстати, в дотнете есть класс, представляющий только дату без времени, называется `DateOnly` - вот его [исходный код](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/DateOnly.cs).

Comment: Вы это серьёзно? Класс - то есть ссылочный тип - для работы с датой? Огребёте проблем, случайно изменив значение экземпляра, уже переданного куда-то.

Comment: @aepot - DateOnly **не класс**! **Структура**!

Comment: Посмотрел код. Ладно, сменю гнев на милость. Класс сделан неизменяемым - это устраняет проблему.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, точно, ошибся.